# Get the index of selected text using JavaFX WebView

Tags: java, webview, javafx-2, javafx

I am trying to get the index of selected text from webview using javafx according to html file.

My query is that suppose index of stackoverflow in a html file is 200 then if i select stackoverflow word in webview then it should return the same index 200 . For getting the selected text i am using the following code

```
       try{
         String selection = (String) webView.getEngine()
         .executeScript("window.getSelection().toString()");
         System.out.println(selection);
        }

      catch(Exception ex)

     {  
     ex.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Comment: how do you even define the index of a word?